# Postgresql get different schema table columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a query. I'm using a few schemas. I want to get different schema table column names.

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='public.combine' 
   or table_name='kds.2014_new' 
   or table_name='public.point' 
   or table_name='spt.point'
```

When I run this query I get 0 result. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first try `select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate `table_name` and `table_schema`

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE (table_name = 'combine' AND table_schema = 'public')
    OR (table_name = '2016_new' AND table_schema = 'kds')
    OR (table_name = 'point' AND table_schema = 'public')
    OR (table_name = 'point' AND table_schema = 'spt')
```